# Running a program using subprocess in Python

Tags: python, sys

I am trying to run the program `220_beta_1e-2_47_53ND.py` using `subprocess.run()`. But the program doesn't run. Can somebody please help?

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.run(['python3.9.7 220_beta_1e-2_47_53ND.py'],shell=True)
```

Comment: You should try `subprocess.run(['python3.9.7', '220_beta_1e-2_47_53ND.py'],shell=True)`, just in case. If it still does not work, check your python file, are you sure it is correct ?

Comment: I mean this script runs but ```220_beta_1e-2_47_53ND.py``` doesn't seem to run.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't run"? Did you fix the call to *run()* as @ThéoRubenach suggested?

Comment: you need to ask a proper question, so i am going to ask the required questions for any meaningful answer. what happens when the above program runs ? any error message ? what does that python file do ? what did you expect to happen ? what actually happened ? how are you sure the program didn't run ? (keep in mind the program can run and you just don't see the output), where is this script relative to your script ?

Comment: The above program runs fine. There's no error message. But I was expecting the above program to run ```220_beta_1e-2_47_53ND.py```. If it did actually run this script, I would know but it doesn't run this script.

Comment: people shouldn't have to extract information from you in order to help you .... anyway i would like to point out that `subprocess.run` doesn't print the output of the script to your screen so if you are expecting something to be printed on screen, it won't happen, good luck debugging this on your own.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: when you use `shell=True` then you should use `single string` without list - and it may be good to use full path - ie. `subprocess.run('/full/path/to/python3.9.7 /full/path/to/220_beta_1e-2_47_53ND.py', shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

When the argument to `subprocess.run()` is a list, the command and arguments should be separate list elements, not a single string. You also shouldn't use `shell=True` -- that's only used when you supply a single string and it uses shell syntax that needs to be processed.

```
subprocess.run(['python3.9.7', '220_beta_1e-2_47_53ND.py'])
```

Comment: Using the above, I get the following error: ```...FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified```.

Comment: Try using the full path to the python script.